# Wordpress WPforms action hooks before sending email

Tags: wordpress

I use wordpress wpforms and I need to find/replace a text in every email before sending. Is there a hook for it prior to sending so I can modify it on functions.php?

Comment: You know, you could look at their documentation: https://wpforms.com/developers/wpforms_email_message/

Answer (score 1):

https://wpforms.com/developers/wpforms_process_complete/

do_action( 'wpforms_process_complete', array $fields, array $entry, array $form_data, int $entry_id )

Comment: This won't filter the email message. Also, according to the docs, this fires AFTER the email is sent: _Saving the entry to the database and sending the email notifications are done prior to this hook running._